# Как правильно доставать элементы второго Observable, когда в первом вызывается onNext (RxJava 2)

Tags: android, rxjava, rxjava2

Есть задача, есть две подписки на разные данные из бд (Requery), данные из этих подписок мне нужны одновременно, условно

```
WeightDao.weightInfo()
        .doOnNext(weightInfos ->
                WeightDao.weightGoals()
                        .subscribe(weightGoals -> update(new Pair<>(weightInfos, weightGoals))))
        .subscribe();
```

Каждая из подписок ждет изменений в бд до тех пор пока не вызвать Dispose. То есть onComplete не вызывается и данные для страницы мы получаем реактивно, как только засунем их в бд.

Этот пример работает, всякий раз когда я добавляю или редактирую данные и сохраняю их в бд у меня дергается онНекст у первой подписки, в котором дерается сабскрайб второй и отрабатывает метод update

Но учитывая смысл RxJava все не должно быть настолько громоздко и наверняка есть способ выразить это все куда более емко и правильно.

Если сделать так:

```
Observable.zip(
        WeightDao.weightInfo(),
        WeightDao.weightGoals(),
        Pair::new
).subscribe(this::update);
```

то после того, как сабскрипшн отработает вызовется onComplete для метода zip, и любые изменения в бд не отразятся в методе update

Такой вариант тоже не работает:

```
WeightDao.weightInfo()
        .zipWith(WeightDao.weightGoals(), Pair::new)
        .subscribe(this::update);
```

Точнее работает, но один раз, как я поимаю при первом эмите дергается сабскрайб у второго Observable и мы получаем одновременно данные, но потом при изменении WeightInfo в бд ничего не произойдет, потому что подписка будет ждать онНекст у WeightDao.weightGoals(), а оно явно не вызывается.

Пытался так же сделать join, но похоже я так и не понял, как его использовать, потому что в сабскрайб ничего не пришло, когда я сделал так

```
WeightDao.weightInfo()
        .join(WeightDao.weightGoals(),
              Observable::just,
              Observable::just,
              Pair::new)
        .subscribe(this::update);)
```

Можем ли всякий раз форсированно дергать элементы из второй подписки, в onNext первой?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как я понял мне нужен combineLatest

```
Observable.combineLatest(
        WeightDao.weightInfo(),
        WeightDao.weightGoals(),
        Pair::new)
    .subscribe(this::update);
```

пойду проверять